# Align JavaScript imports "from" Statement to be Vertically Aligned

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, import, prettier

I would like the end result of my imports to be like this, via a tool that can automatically format my code `onSave`:

```
import { Stack, StackProps, Duration, Resource } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { LambdaStack }                           from "./lambda-Stack";
import { Construct }                             from "constructs";
```

How can I align all of the "from" statements vertically in VS Code? I've looked at both prettier and eslint.

Answer (score 1):

Prettier doesn't care what you want. :-) It's an *opinionated* tool useful for applying consistency to code within teams (and for avoiding arguments about different formatting styles [although you just get arguments about whether to use Prettier instead]).

If you don't want Prettier's formatting, don't use Prettier. There are other code formatters, some of which offer more control than Prettier does.

You *could* tell Prettier to ignore each of those import statements:

```
// prettier-ignore
import { Stack, StackProps, Duration, Resource } from "aws-cdk-lib";
// prettier-ignore
import { LambdaStack }                           from "./lambda-Stack";
// prettier-ignore
import { Construct }                             from "constructs";
```

or

```
/* prettier-ignore*/ import { Stack, StackProps, Duration, Resource } from "aws-cdk-lib";
/* prettier-ignore*/ import { LambdaStack }                           from "./lambda-Stack";
/* prettier-ignore*/ import { Construct }                             from "constructs";
```

For now there's no "block ignore" in Prettier for JavaScript (only for [certain select other languages](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#range-ignore)), although there's [an open request for one](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5287).

Comment: This answer does not answer my question. My question was "How can I align all of the "from" statements vertically in VS Code?". You've started your answer with  "Prettier doesn't care what you want. :-)"

Comment: @Lloukas - You tagged [tag:prettier] on the question, so I answered with an answer about Prettier. If you didn't want people to do that, you shouldn't use the tag.

Answer (score 0):

In the `.vscode/settings.json` file

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
 "source.fixAll": false,
 "source.fixAll.eslint": false,
 "source.organizeImports": true,
},
```

`source.organizeImports` should be set to `true` if you want VS Code to align your imports for you.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, with prettier or eslint you might want to limit printWidth to defined number of caracter per line. So imagine if you have many imports or long module name :

```js
                /* You better should break line overhere |----------| */
import { DepA, DepB, DepC, DepD, DepE, DepF, DepG, DepH, DepI, DepJ } from "./some-long-named-module";
import { OnlyOneImport }                                              from "./other-module";
```

So my answer is not responding to "how can you align 'from' statements?" but it
may open another question 'should you ?'

Here is a common way to indent imports :

```js
// common way to write import with vertical (Automatable)
import { 
  DepA, 
  DepB, 
  DepC, 
  DepD, 
  DepE, 
  DepF, 
  DepG, 
  DepH, 
  DepI, 
  DepJ 
} from "./some-long-named-module";
import { OnlyOneImport } from "./other-module";
```

Here is the eslint rule to auto indent your code : https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-curly-newline

example for `object-curly-newline` rule in eslint:

```json
# .estlintrc.json
{
 ...
 "rules": {
    ...
    "object-curly-newline": [
      "error",
      {
          "consistent": true,
          "multiline": true
      }
    ]
 }
}
```

PS:

Here some example of how I use it

```json
# .estlintrc.json
{
  "root": true,
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base", // See https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb
    "airbnb-base/whitespace", 
    "plugin:jest/recommended", // See https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jest
    "prettier" // See https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier
  ],
  "env": {
    "jest/globals": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "jest",
    "...whatever-you-want"
  ],
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "dist/",
    "node_modules/",
    "...whatever-you-want"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
      "error",
      "WithStatement",
      "BinaryExpression[operator='in']"
    ],
    "no-console": [
      0,
      {
        "allow": [
          "info",
          "warn",
          "error"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      "avoid-escape"
    ],
    "object-curly-newline": [
      "error",
      {
          "consistent": true,
          "multiline": true
      }
    ],
    "...whatever-you-want"
  }
}
```

```json
# .prettierrc
{
    "printWidth": 80,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "useTabs": false,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "quoteProps": "as-needed",
    "jsxSingleQuote": false,
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "bracketSameLine": false,
    "proseWrap": "preserve",
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "endOfLine": "lf",
    "parser": "babel"
}
```